# google analytics event tracking for PDF downloads, Generic approach

Tags: google-analytics, ascx, sitefinity

I need to implement the GA tracking event for PDF file downloads, For that had searched a lot and found out many code where i can add some code to links and track them from GA's content section, But the problem is I do have a lot of PDF link on the page and don't want to edit every link and I want the code to be generic for future uploaded links also.
So what would be the best approach for this task, Any referral links would do or any code would be highly appreciated .
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore the use of Google Tag Manager, where you can create a generic tag that will return to you information for each individual link. GTM uses things called "macros" which is like a template that returns useful information including the clicked element's ID, or pathname (which in your case for the PDF files, would all be different). So in this way, you would only need to call this macro each time a PDF file is clicked. No coding is involved using this standard approach through GTM. Here's a link to a descriptive explanation: http://porcelainduck.com/2014/03/track-pdf-downloads-google-tag-manager/. You can see that it uses the {{element URL}} macro that returns the PDF's unique URL. GTM not only applies to current links, but also all future links.

Comment: This sounds something great and to the requirement ..Thanks for the help I'll see to it and will check correct Ans if it's working

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tags which you've used to mark your question with you're using C#, ASP.NET

If that's the case, can't you create a base page that on rendering replaces all the

Comment: well the case is, this thing is an add on to a project which is already in production and i am not that expert to comment on will i be able to do that but i think i wont be able to do big changes. and i am sorry i have to change tags as i am doing this in sitefinity and thinking of adding custom ascx control on it. will change the tags .. thanks

Comment: Ok, my help goes to here, I don't know anything about Sitefinity.

Comment: no issues but i appreciate your time and efforts .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a click event with JQuery to all links or all links inside the download widget class. Inside the click handler I would then grab the link text and use that as part of the Google analytics event you fire.